# Is there a way to configure my code-runner to set my Python interpretor from my conda? I am using a virtualenv from conda in the VSCode terminal

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, conda, vscode-code-runner

Am trying to find a quick keyboard shortcut to execute Python scripts on VSCode while using conda virtual environment on a Mac.

I have not been able to find the settings of code-runner to do this.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the `python` run command path in `code-runner.executorMap` in `settings.json`, like this:

```
{
    "code-runner.executorMap": {
        "python": "python"
    }
}
```

Of course, all of this requires you to properly set up the local environment.

The shortcut key settings can be opened with the shortcut keys `Cmd+k, Cmd+t`.

But I recommend separating read and write from other operations. I only use Visual Studio Code to read and write text. Other operations are basically performed using CLI software.

As for `Conda`, although I have not used it, I have read some information. After `Conda` configuration, I think there should still use the python command to execute the script.

The information which I have read is from [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/300128/how-can-i-run-a-python-script-using-anaconda-from-the-command-line#answer-318719).